# R expression in multi-labels

Tags: r, expression, label, cut

I've tried expression and `bquote`, but can't figure this one out...

I have a continuous variable, call it `x`. I cut it using `cut(...)` to create a factor with two levels. I want to label these levels `<=10` and `>10` but I'd like to use the expression or `bquote` functions (see `plotmath` function) to replace the `<=` with the nicer version: `≤`

For example:

```
x <- rnorm(100,10,5)
x.10 <- cut(x, breaks=c(-Inf,10,Inf), labels=*expression*)
```

What should I put as the argument to labels so that when I do a barplot of x.10 the labels appear under the bars?

```
barplot(table(x.10))
```

[image: barplot(table(x.10))]

I can get this to work:

```
labs <- expression(x <= ...)

plot(1, main=labs)
```

[image: plot(1, main=labs)]

but how to icorporate that into the barplot labels?

Comment: Having trouble editing this, but hopefully you get my point. Just ignore the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to do expressions as labels to factors. Apply the expression labels on the plot itself, with something like:

```
set.seed(42) # always include a seed in questions with randomness
x <- rnorm(100,10,5)
x.10 <- cut(x, breaks=c(-Inf,10,Inf), labels = FALSE)

labels <- c(expression(paste(x <= 10)), expression(paste(x > 10)))
barplot(table(x.10), names.arg = labels)
```

[image: simple barplot]

Comment: Thanks. So when you say "Don't...", does that mean it can't be done? :)

Comment: I cannot say that it cannot be done. Perhaps I should have said *"don't bang your head against a brick wall too long trying to use expressions as labels"*. It's "not easy" to make the plot labels look "fancy", ergo we need to go through `expression` or `bquote`. The use of labels (e.g., from `cut` or `factor`) is intended to be descriptive, not pretty, so it would not surprise me if doing "fancy" would be a large hack and not necessarily worth the time. But I do not know of a rule or line of code that says it absolutely cannot be done. :-)

Comment: And it seems that paste is not necessary here. Thanks again!

Comment: Thought as much ... I confess I look at plotmath and other docs about it every time I want to make something fancy ... perhaps part of the reason why I suggest against trying to do it with something as pervasive as labels.